# Using array, How to print name of students who has highest marks in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The code i tried

```
function findHighest(){
 var highest = 0; // assum min 0
 var highestItem;
 $('tr').each(function(index, item){
    if(index > 0){
    var math = $(item).find('td').eq(1).text();
    var eng = $(item).find('td').eq(2).text();
    var lit = $(item).find('td').eq(3).text();
    
    //alert(math)
    
    var sum = parseFloat(math) + parseFloat(eng) + parseFloat(lit)
    if (sum > highest){
    highest = sum;
    highestItem = item;
    }
    }
   
   
 })
 
  $(highestItem).css({ 'font-style': 'italic', 'color': 'red' });
```

}

I am trying to find name of student who got highest marks in class in at least two subjects in JavaScript?

Comment: What happens when you run the current code? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Sure will add now

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question**. Don't link to external ressources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const highestMarks=[];
const studentsWithHighestMarks=[];

const students = [{ name: "mini", subject: [{ maths : 20}, {english: 23}, { science: 25}, { sports: 24}] }, { name: "jerry", subject: [{ maths : 22}, {english: 20}, { science: 20}, { sports: 21}] }, { name: "john", subject: [{ maths : 23}, {english: 25}, { science: 20}, { sports: 21}] }];

students.forEach(student=>{
    student.subject.forEach(subject=>{
   
        for(let key in subject){
            var index = highestMarks.findIndex(obj => {
                      return obj.subject === key
                    });
              
            if (index===-1)             {
            highestMarks.push({
                    subject:key,
                    marks:subject[key],
                    students:[student.name]
                })
            
                
                 
             }else if(highestMarks[index].marks<subject[key]){
            highestMarks[index].marks=subject[key];
            highestMarks[index].students=[student.name];
         
        }
        else if(highestMarks[index].marks==subject[key]){
            highestMarks[index].marks=subject[key];
            highestMarks[index].students.push(student.name);
         
        }
        }
    })
   

});

students.forEach(student=>{
    let count=0; 
    highestMarks.forEach(item=>{
     if(item.students.includes(student.name)){
      count++;
     }
    });
    if(count>=2){
      studentsWithHighestMarks.push(student.name)
    }
})


 console.log(studentsWithHighestMarks)
```

Comment: output of above code=> ['mini', 'john']

Comment: i have updated the code little bit. please update it in your code

Comment: @djohnt check above comment

Answer (score 0):

```
const subjectsConsidering = 2;

const getStudentMarks = (student) => {
  const studentMarksList = [];
  student.subject.forEach((subjectData) => {
    studentMarksList.push(Object.values(subjectData)[0]);
  });
  const sum = studentMarksList.sort().reverse().reduce((sum, a, index) => {
    // restrict only for first 2 subjects
    if (index < subjectsConsidering) {
      return sum + a;
    }
    return sum + 0;
  });
  return sum;
}

students.sort((studentA, studentB) => {
  //return 0 for equal marks
  return getStudentMarks(studentA) > getStudentMarks(studentB) ? -1 : 1;
});

console.log(students);
//This gives the sorted array of students having the highest marks in at least 2 subjects.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Transform the data into a more manageable format
// { "subject": [["name", grade], ["name", grade], ["name", grade]] }
let transformed = students.reduce(
  (data, student) => {
    student.subject.forEach(subject => {
      const key = keys(subject)[0];
      const grade = [student.name, subject[key]];
      if (!(key in data)) {
        data[key] = [];
      }
      data[key].push(grade);
    })
    return data;
  },
  {}
)

// Utility function to compare grades
function gradeCompare(a, b) {
  return a[1] > b[1] ? -1 : 1;
}

// List the top student in each subject
let names = Object.keys(transformed).map((subject) => {
  return transformed[subject].sort(gradeCompare)[0][0];
});
// names :: [ "john", "john", "mini", "mini" ]

// Count the student names
let counts = names.reduce((acc, current) => {
  acc[current] = (acc[current] || 0) + 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
// counts :: { john: 2, mini: 2 }

// Find the maximum occurring count
let maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(counts));
// maxCount :: 2

// Filter the keys that have that count
let topStudents = Object.keys(counts).filter(k => counts[k] === maxCount);
// topStudents :: [ "john", "mini" ]
```